# What is the fastest way to do sorted sampling on integer

Tags: r

What is the fastest way to get sorted sampling, with or without replacement?

```
sort(sample(1:10000, 1000))
```

Comment: You can use `sort.int` which would be faster and specify the `method = "radix"`

Comment: `sample(10000, 1000)` is faster than `sample(1:10000, 1000)`